# What powers does a Zauberbiest possess?

Tags: grimm

On *Grimm*, we have seen that Hexenbiests and Zauberbiests are in a sense opposite-sex counterparts. However, they are not simply two names for the same thing. Hexenbiest blood, for example, has properties that Zauberbiest blood does not.

With regard to Hexenbiests, we know they have wide variety of abilities, depending on strength:

- All have enhanced physical strength.
- They can perform a variety of rituals and brew potions.
- They can have varying degrees of telekinesis, depending on power, with Juliette of course being the most extreme example.
- Powerful Hexenbiests can have other powers, such as altering or reshaping flesh.

On the other hand, most of our information on Zauberbiests comes from Captain Renard, who is not a full Zauberbiest. Nonetheless, besides an incomplete woge, the only power he seems to possess is enhanced strength. On the other hand, the main example of a full Zauberbiest (Bonaparte) seemed to have similar powers to Hexenbiests, which fits neither with Renard's apparent lack of abilies, nor the aforementioned differences between Hexenbiests and Zauberbiests.

Is there any information on what powers Zauberbiests in general have, and how they differ from those of Hexenbiests?

Comment: Well, Bonaparte could do some pretty freaky stuff, he seemed to be pretty powerful. I also think that, due to the differences between Hexenbiests and Zauberbiests, Zaubers are immune to the whole "Ingesting Grimm blood takes away your powers" thing, though of course this has never been tried.

Comment: You also have to bear in mind that Eve was created, not born, and Diana is a unique, 3/4 Hexenbiest, 1/4 Royal blend. Zauberbiests also have the capability to perform rituals and spells, their only limitation is that they can't perform blood magic. Though, often they're so powerful in other areas that they don't need to.